# Arduino WiFi shield not communicating

Tags: arduino

I'm using the Official Wifi shield on a Uno R3.

Everything was working fine in the beginning.

But now, the Uno couldn't communicate with the WiFi shield whether it's plug in with USB or with a 9V battery. I could still control the L9 LED on the Wifi shield, but the WiFi function isn't working anymore.  I'm returned a
WL_Connected = False, when I did WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);

I did notice, even when it was working, when I switched the the 9V battery from laptop power, it doesn't always power up immediately.

How do I even begin to trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Swapping out boards/shields. It could be something simple like a bad pin.

Answer (score -1):

The WiFi shield was based on a transceiver made by ZeroG. Now this company was bought from Microchip and of course they don't support Atmel processors anymore.

I had the same problem and I switched to another amazing product: Flyport Wi-Fi that has a processor onboard (PIC24) and this transceiver. It's also open source, look to www.openpicus.com